# How to export a jar with its database?

Tags: java, mysql, jar, export

I need to export my project

Im using Eclipse and MYSQL. My project is working fine in IDE and my database is already connected.

> The problem is that I don't know how/where should i start?

I read things about like making a file contains manifest.mf, exporting project through runnable jar,  maven etc. As a result of reading and searching too much of "how to export it", those things made me more confuse and i don't know what should i do anymore.

What i want to do is for someone on other computer can access my application without opening an ide or sql (is it possible?)

So can someone clarify and give me guide how to export your whole project + database in *the most simplest way* if possible, because im new to this thing.

Comment: Ah, so you are running in your local "development" environment, and now you want to run it in "production". You'll need to **deploy** it. Now, you need to deploy two things: 1) The application as a single jar file (any build tool like Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc.) can produce a jar file with the whole app. 2) The database; the production database will need to be accessible from the client computers; probably you want to install it in a shared server or in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Use an embedded database and setup the database in the start of your application.

The main contenders in the java space are HSQLDB, H2 and Apache Derby.

If this is not required by your application it will be an extra hurdle, then evaluate the trade off between changing the application to use an embedded database versus setting up a server to be accessed from the other computer.